# Is `movq rax, xmm0` buggy in Radare2?

Tags: radare2, debuggers, x86-64, emulation

Why doesn't `rax` get loaded from `xmm0` here?  `radare2` bug?

GitHub issue [`movq rax, xmm0` doesn't work in native debugger](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues/16778) filed.

```
[0x0003b0e0]> drr
role reg    value            ref
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
SN   rax    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     rbx    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A3   rcx    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A2   rdx    7ff0000000000000 
A1   rsi    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A0   rdi    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A4   r8     0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A5   r9     0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A6   r10    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A7   r11    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r12    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r13    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r14    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r15    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
PC   rip    3b0ee             241902 (.text) sym.finite R X 'movq rax, xmm0'
BP   rbp    10078000          268926976 R W 0x0 -->  0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     rflags 0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
SP   rsp    10078000          268926976 R W 0x0 -->  0 R 0x3010102464c457f
[0x0003b0e0]> dr xmm0
0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5555555555555555
[0x0003b0e0]> ds
[0x0003b0e0]> drr
role reg    value            ref
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
SN   rax    8000000000000000 
     rbx    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A3   rcx    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A2   rdx    7ff0000000000000 
A1   rsi    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A0   rdi    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A4   r8     0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A5   r9     0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A6   r10    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
A7   r11    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r12    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r13    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r14    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     r15    0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
PC   rip    3b0f3             241907 (.text) sym.finite R X 'and rax, rdx'
BP   rbp    10078000          268926976 R W 0x0 -->  0 R 0x3010102464c457f
     rflags 0                 0 R 0x3010102464c457f
SP   rsp    10078000          268926976 R W 0x0 -->  0 R 0x3010102464c457f
[0x0003b0e0]>
```

Comment: can you share the binary?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik  It's the `finite` function in `/lib64/libm-2.28.so`.

Comment: Please add an answer with the resolution.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Done!  I'll wait a day to accept it in case somebody else writes a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `movq rax, xmm0` buggy in Radare2?

No, it's just not fully implemented in all debuggers yet.

### Native Debugger Works!

This instruction works fine using the native debugger.  The native debugger is launched with `r2 -d yourFileGoesHere`.  Alternatively, if you are already in `r2` looking at the file, but `r2` wasn't launched with the `-d` switch, the file can be reopened in debug mode with the `r2` command `ood` (o_pen o_penned file with the d_ebugger ?).

### [ESIL](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/disassembling/esil.html) [Emulator](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/analysis/emulation.html) doesn't fully support SIMD yet.

See Github issues [#4327](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues/4327) and [#11421](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues/11421)

The "bug" noted in the question was actually demonstrating that the ESIL Emulator doesn't fully support the `xmm0` register yet.

### Summary

The native debugger accurately executes the `movq rax, xmm0` instruction.  The ESIL Emulator does not accurately emulate the `movq rax, xmm0` instruction *yet*.